# How to Implement Extension Method in Abstract Class

Tags: c#

I'm developing an MVVM-based library and I'd like to incorporate this extension method for my ObservableObject abstract class.

```
public static ObservableObject  FirstOrDefaultInstance(this IEnumerable<ObservableObject> items)
   {
      return items.FirstOrDefault() ?? new ObservableObject();
   }
```

Obviously, this won't work. But how can my derived types inherit this extension with an implementation of their own default constructor?

Comment: I'm puzzled by your question, when you say "how can my derived types inherit this extension", because extension methods are not meant to be inherited. Could you clarify?

Comment: I want an inherited extension method.

Comment: What do you mean by an "inherited extension method"? An extension method applies to a type and all types that can be assigned to it. For example, an extension method on `System.Object` will apply to everything. An extension method on `IEnumerable` will apply to `Array`, but not to `Int32`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `new()` [generics constraint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx) on generic method if specifying/inferring concrete type in invocation works for you:

```
public static FirstOrDefaultInstance<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items)
   where T: ObservableObject, new()
{
   return items.FirstOrDefault() ?? new T();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know about that syntax.